# What else do I need to do to view the website on my computer from the outside world?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, home-networking, ubuntu-16.04

In my house, I've got a desktop connected to the modem/router via Ethernet cable. On this Ubuntu 16.04 desktop I'm running a webserver on `0.0.0.0:8000`, so when I go to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/directory/` in my browser on this desktop, I see the website I'm serving. I'd like to connect to this website from other computers not in my house.

Steps I've done so far:

1. Opened the firewall on my desktop `sudo ufw allow 8000` to allow the outside world to connect to my computer.
2. set a static IP address for my desktop by `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` then adding the lines with numbers I got from `ifconfig`:

   ```
   iface eth0 inet static
    address (with the inet number here)
    netmask (with the Mask number here)
    gateway (with the Bcast number here)
   ```
3. Added port forwarding in my router with the values

   ```
   Service Type: TCP/UDP
   Server IPv4 Address: (same as inet/address number above)
   Server IPv6 Address: (has some numbers here for the first 4 then 4 blank ones, maybe this is what I'm missing?)
   Start Port: 8000
   End Port: 8000
   ```

In the router admin I see a WAN IP Address, `xx.xxx.xx.xx`

So, now that I've done all this, I expect to go to `xx.xxx.xx.xx:8000` in my browser on my phone when it's not connected to the WiFi and see my nice little website, the same I see in the browser on my desktop. Instead, I get a "Could not connect to server". Sad!

Can anyone see any steps or misconfiguration I'm missing that would prevent me from seeing my website?

EDIT: I've changed my server on my local computer because of the comment by @tetsujin so that it hosts at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: [0.0.0.0 is an unroutable address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), & cannot be used as you are attempting. Your local machine sees it the same as 127.0.0.1, but it is not the same thing.

Comment: I'm just going to put in a small warning against using an out of box web server configuration in any personal or unprotected network.  A default instance of many web server products are unsecured for development reasons, and opening ports into your router can lead to an internal network breach.  Be cautious and read all documentation regarding securing your web server instance before going live.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is a typo, but yes, I see a misconfiguration.

In your static IP configuration you put on your desktop, you said you used the "Bcast number" for gateway.

That is not correct. The gateway is the IP address of your router. Without the proper gateway IP you also can't access the internet from your desktop.

Also, it's important to note that you should not re-use your existing dynamic IP and set it for the static IP on your desktop. Your router has a pool of IP addresses available that it hands out dynamically to each device via DHCP. You need to choose a static IP address that is outside this range. If you re-use the IP address the router handed you dynamically, it is likely it will eventually hand that IP address out to a different device and cause an IP address conflict.

Check your router configuration, determine the IP pool it has available for DHCP, modify it to a smaller range if necessary, then set a new static IP on your desktop, outside the DHCP range, and make sure you specify the IP address of your router for the gateway address in your static IP configuration.

Comment: When you say `The gateway is the IP address of your router` do you mean this is the same IP that I get when I search "what is my ip" on google, and is listed as `WAN IP Address` in my router admin interface?

Comment: No. Your router's internal IP address on your network. It is usually like 192.168.1.1 or something like that. The same IP you use when you connect to reconfigure your router.

Comment: More specifically, it is called the `LAN` interface or `LAN IP Address`.

Answer (score 0):

1. 0.0.0.0 is all addresses on internet
2. you need static IP on ISP side of your internet
3. then you can set your modem/router for IP forward to your local machine or create DMZ

Comment: He doesn't necessarily need a static IP.  It's suggested but it'll function as long as he knows his external IP.  He can also use dynamic DNS services and register a domain name if he wanted to take it a step further.